# Store secret file with spring boot config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I use Spring Cloud Config to store JPA credentials in a GIT repository.
My application use spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap to get the configuration (I don't use specific server as I just have one application)

I think it is logic to place a secret file (google-keys.json) in the same secure GIT repository.

How could I get the content of this file from my Java app ?
I don't need mapping of the JSon, I can update the file to be a yml file and I can create a corresponding POJO (anyway, I just need the content String).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to store all your secrets under environment variables.
It's never safe to store any password under Git repo.

You have 2 options to retrieve it:

- option (1) you can retrieve it using system:

> ```
> System.getEnv()
> ```

- option (2) since you are using spring boot, you can use Environment:

> ```
> import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
>
> private final Environment environment;
>
> password = environment.getProperty("jpa.credentials");
> ```